# Measure object depth with ray_cast

Tags: python, measurement

There is a template script:
operator_modal_view3d_raycast.py
That show how use the ray_cast() to find the the coordinates of hit face.
But I want to measure the distance of the opposite face from the hit face.
The depth of the object from the 3d view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [mathutils.geometry.intersect_ray_tri](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_63_8/mathutils.geometry.html?highlight=intersect_ray_tri#mathutils.geometry.intersect_ray_tri) to check any intersections with object triangles.
2. You can use the raycast method and then again with normals inverted to get the opposite face

Comment: Yes, the second metod is better, but use two times ray_cast, the second time with start point the Hit point of the first and end point the obj matrix.